# Javascript error in internet explorer for sharepoint sites

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am having a sharepoint 2010 blog site. When i am trying to create a post on the blog using Internet explorer 8, i am getting the javascript error as below on the left bottom corner. But if i revert the site to 2007 look and feel, i am able to create the post. But after doing the visual upgrade to 2010, we are unable to create the post.

Error : "null" is null or not an object.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sivakumar P

Comment: please find what line is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You have a Javascript Object somewhere, which is named "null". Try finding and renaming it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Here the issue is before doing the visual upgrade, we are able to create post. But after visual upgrade, we are not able to create post. What will cause this javascript error after the visual upgrade